# Is there a way to request unmigration

Tags: support, migration

I'm not sure the reason why my question was migrated. Is there any process to reopen the question?

Comment: Can you show the question in question?

Comment: I think this is the question you refer to - [For those who have used alternative string types/libraries to cstrings (describe your experience)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/67485)

Comment: If that is the question then it was certainly off topic for Stack Overflow - if only because **there's no code**. It's also a marginal question for Programmers - as it's a list question.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Flag both questions for moderator attention. Why? Because a **copy** of the question is migrated to the new site and is therefore a separate (though linked) entity.

The original question needs flagging so that the migration history can be cleared and the question re-opened.

The migrated question needs flagging so that it can be deleted.

The moderators from both sites need to coordinate this.

All of the above assumes that the moderators agree that the question was migrated incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the question you refer to

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/67485

but I think that question does not have exact answers and kind of discussion, means off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Those question use to migrated to programmers site recently, migration looks ok for me though.

but you may try to flag it as to migrate back (and better with Community Wiki as @Will mentioned in comment)

Comment: I agree it's off topic for Stack Overflow, but it's barely on topic for Programmers. I'll wait to see what sort of answers it gets.

Comment: Could have been wiki'd at SO and been marginally acceptable.

Comment: @Will: Or closed as being off-topic but certainly not moved to Programmers.